# Reference to previous value/set in function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula to only show values if it isn't zero, `-100%`, or an error:

`=IF(IFERROR((AA92 - AA91) / AA91; ); IF((AA92 - AA91) / AA91 = -100%; ; (AA92 - AA91) / AA91); )`

What it does is basically

```
if (output == error) {
  display("")
} else if (output == "-100%") {
  display("")
} else {
  display(output)
}
```

Is it possible to make some sort of reference to `(AA92-AA91) / AA91` so I don't have to continuously repeat that part, without using a named range? As you might guess, I use this formula on several hundreds of rows

Comment: did the formula I wrote work?

Comment: @MattKing It did! Thanks a bunch :) I've updated all of my sheets that use a similar formula with your formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rM6XsXcDhbw1Guq4g8XIYXH1041ukD45rFaujwg2NsE/edit?usp=sharing) has been specially made for this question.  This formula in cell B1 (*and only cell B1)* might be what you're looking for but didn't know was possible(?)

={"% Dif";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(A2:A/A1:A-1,ROWS(A2:A),1))))}

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR((AA92:AA1000 - AA91:AA999) / AA91:AA999; ); 
 IF((AA92:AA1000 - AA91:AA999) / AA91:AA999 = -100%; ; 
 (AA92:AA1000 - AA91:AA999) / AA91:AA999); ))
```